# ClientSide Update Using AJAX for PagedList

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor, pagedlist

I have a MVC application that uses PagedList for paging. The first column is a checkbox. If a user selects a row, I want that to stay preserved throughout the paging (ie: User selects row 1 on page 1, then goes to page 5, and goes back to page 1, I want row 1 to still be checked). I can't seem to figure out how to use Ajax on top of this in order to achieve a solution. Any ideas?

```
@foreach (var appUser in Model)
{
    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black; font-size: 12px;">
    <div class="one column alpha">
        @Html.CheckBox("chkUser" + @appUser.appUserId)
    </div>
    <div class="two columns alpha">
        <img src="@appUser.appUserProfileImage" alt="@appUser.appUserHandle" />
    </div>
    <div class="two columns omega">
        @appUser.appUserHandle
    </div>
    <div class="four columns omega">
        @appUser.appUserStatus
    </div>
    <div class="three columns omega" style="text-align: right;">
        <input type="button" value="Mail @appUser.appUserHandle" id="btnMail" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MailUser", "Settings")';return false;" />
    </div>
    </div>
}
    <br />
    <div class="row">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("AppUsers", "Settings",
            new { p = page, id = ViewBag.Id, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
    </div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is to have it visually there, or it is just to once you click something it sends all the selected ids or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking in having a hidden to hold a list of IDs of selected items.
The hidden should be outside of the container that holds the paged list (to avoid overriding it).

So, once done selecting items, and on submit the form, the selected items can be got from the hidden.

About the requirement to keep item selected when I go back to that page, you should check the ids in your table comparing to checked ids in the hidden. If you find it, check the corresponding checkbox. This is done via jQuery.

Other option is that in each page change, you submit current selected users, and do the check in your Razor code (AKA sever side). I think is better the jQuery one.